# Textarea is not getting focus when modal jQuery UI dialog has opened

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

When I try to click textarea with id "customNotepad" it's not getting focus when UI dialog has opened. However, I am able to resize the textarea. When I click the div with ID "Header" it's giving an alert also.

```css
#customNotepad{      
    z-index:1002 !important;
 position:absolute !important;      
}
#noteText{      
    z-index:1000;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Dialog - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog({   modal: true});
    
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  
  <div id=customNotepad><div id="Header"><span id="Btn" onclick={alert()}>ClrButton</span><span id="">Title</span></div>
    <div id="notepadContent">
      <textarea maxlength="150" id="noteText"  style="width:100%;height:100%;"></textarea></div>
  </div> 
       
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
  <p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
</div>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you declare model as true `{ modal: true }` in your code so how can you set focus on `textarea` you can use `{ modal: false }` instead true.

Comment: No i want modal dialog also at the same time i want to type in textarea

Answer (score 0):

This is simply impossible. A modal dialog, by definition, doesn't allow interaction with other elements on the page.

If you want to be able to use the textarea, just don't make it modal.

I really don't see any benefit to having a modal dialog here, and some harm.

Reference: http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-modal

Comment: In real application i have a floating notepad so i want to interact with that textarea when jquery Ui dialog modal is opened... Ui dialog modal is showing some other content in actual application.

Comment: It just won't work. The dialog will work better if it's not modal.

Comment: if i change my floating notepad also as a dialog then i can able to type in textarea but that dialog modal giving styles borders and containers.